How to create Encounters using EPIC FHIR API?
I'm working on integrating Epic FHIR APIs into my custom EHR application. One of my requirements is to create new Encounters (e.g., linking them to appointments or other workflows). However, after thoroughly exploring the Epic FHIR documentation and available APIs, I haven't found a specific endpoint or method to create an Encounter.
From my understanding so far:
The Encounter resource in Epic FHIR APIs only supports Read and Search operations, as specified in the documentation (R4 version).
Other related resources, like Appointment, seem to allow creation, but I don't see a direct way to create Encounters.
Am I missing something here? Is there a specific workflow in Epic where Encounters are created automatically (e.g., when an Appointment is confirmed), or do Encounters need to be manually created via some other method (like HL7v2 or native Epic interfaces)?

If you look at https://fhir.epic.com/Sandbox, you'll see that there is no 'create' operation currently supported in Epic's FHIR API.  Their v2 interface has support for exchanging information about external encounters, but I believe the expectation is that for encounters that are internal to the Epic system, they can't be created via an API.  You'd have to reach out to Epic directly to learn more.
